# Redux axios action include variabel params in request from function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux, axios

Currently I am struggling to get the follow task to be done, which should be very simple I guess.

I have a userAction.jsx file where I am able to make an API call to check if an user exists. I would like te make the parameters I send along the api call variable so I make this function more flexible and reusable.

The function look likes as follow;

```
export function userExists(email) {

    return function(dispatch) {

        axios.get('http://apiserver.com/api/users.php', {
            params : {
                email : email
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({ type : "USER_EXISTS_FULFILLED", payload : response.data })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                dispatch({ type : "USER_EXISTS_REJECTED", payload : err })
            });
    }
}
```

the 'params' part with the parameters should become variabel so I can do something like this in the dispatcher => dispatch(userExists({ email : values.email }). I don't get it to make this work when I do something like this:

```
export function userExists(params) {

    return function(dispatch) {

        axios.get('http://apiserver.com/api/users.php', {
            params : {
                params
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({ type : "USER_EXISTS_FULFILLED", payload : response.data })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                dispatch({ type : "USER_EXISTS_REJECTED", payload : err })
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to spread the object:

```
params: {
    ...email
}
```